# How to return a csv using a curl?

Tags: php, api, csv, download

Building an API for a PHP application where I query for data, put it into an array of object like:

```
success: [
  {name: 'X', isActive: true},
  {name: 'Y', isActive: true},
  {name: 'Z', isActive: true}
]
```

My PHP code:

```
private function receiptHistoryToCsv($rowData) {
        $filename = "export.csv";
        $delimeter=";";
        header('Content-Type: application/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');

        // Initialize a file pointer for the csv
        $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        foreach ($rowData as $row) {
            fputcsv($file, $row, $delimeter);
        }

        fclose($file);

        return $file;
}

public function getCSV() {

  $tableHeaders = array ('name', 'is active');
  $rowData = array();

  // Add headers (acting like column names)
  array_push($rowData, $tableHeaders);

  $information = getInfoUsingDBQuery();

  foreach($information as $row) {
    $name = strval($row["name"]);
    $isActive = $row["isActive"];
    array_push($rowData, array($name, $is_active));
  }

  // $rowData now looks like the success array above.

  return receiptHistoryToCsv($rowData);
}
```

`Endpoint`: `localhost:8080/api/getCSV`

On the frontend, there's a button with the text `Download CSV`.

How can I convert the array into a csv file and then return the csv in a downloadable format when the button is clicked?

For starters, I'd like to just go to the endpoint and get a csv to start downloading automatically.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us what you have tried that is not working as expected. What you want to do is certainly feasible but we're not here to write the code for you I'm afraid.

Comment: My bad. I'll add my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just able to make it work.

```
public function receiptHistoryToCsv($rowData) {
        $filename = "export.csv";

        header('Content-Type: application/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');

        $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        foreach ($rowData as $row) {
            fputcsv($file, $row);
        }

        fclose($file);

        // This is probably what made it work.
        ob_flush();
}

public function getCSV() {

  $tableHeaders = array ('name', 'is active');
  $rowData = array();

  // Add headers (acting like column names)
  array_push($rowData, $tableHeaders);

  $information = getInfoUsingDBQuery();

  foreach($information as $row) {
    $name = strval($row["name"]);
    $isActive = $row["isActive"];
    array_push($rowData, array($name, $is_active));
  }

  // $rowData now looks like the success array above.

  return this->receiptHistoryToCsv($rowData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can output the results of the `getInfoUsingDBQuery()` function directly without reading them into an intermediate array.

```
public function getCSV() {
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv";');
    $keys = ['name' => 'name', 'isActive' => 'is active'];
    $delimiter=";";
    $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputcsv($file, $keys, $delimiter);
    foreach (getInfoUsingDBQuery() as $row) {
        fputcsv($file, array_intersect_key($row, $keys), $delimiter);
    }
}
```

You shouldn't need to explicitly close the output stream or flush the buffer as this will happen automatically when the script terminates.